# how to parameterize URI in getMongo processor

Tags: apache-nifi

my flow looks like this => generateFF->updateAttribute->getMongo

I am getting following exception

```
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with 'mongodb://'
        at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:203)
        at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:176)
        at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:158)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.mongodb.AbstractMongoProcessor.createClient(AbstractMongoProcessor.java:191)`
```

I am setting mongoURI in "updateAttribute" and I can see it in ff attribute too. and in getMongo I am putting URI as => ${mongo_uri}

issue is, processor gives error as soon as i start the flow, even before ff reached to processor. If processor allows expression language, shouldn't it wait for ff to reach it, so that we can use some type of expression?

am i missing something? or URI has to be hard coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `NiFi-1.8.0` documentation `Mongo URI`

- Supports Expression Language: true but **(will be evaluated using variable registry only)**

So this processor **wont have scope to get flowfile attributes**.

Keep MongoURI as a **varible** in [vairable registry](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/154951/introduce-a-ui-driven-variable-registry-starting-f.html) then processor will gets the value of the variable.

[image]

Comment: ok, another issue i am facing is, once getMongo is done, I loose all my attributes, as mongo seems to be creating new FF. but then where to store run time values? i always though, and used updateAttribute to initialize variable, and then used them during the flow. But now I have getMongo in middle of my flow, i am loosing all my variable. Is registry variable useful for this? if no, then whats solution? if yes, then can I update them during execution? and will they go back to initial value, before next run? I am on 1.6 version

Comment: @RakeshPrasad, This issue got fixed in NiFi-1.8 jira addressing this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5334, To work around this **issue please refer to this link**.. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/188338/attributes-lost-after-running-selecthiveql.html..

Comment: thanks, upgrade was not an option so went with workaround.